# How to synchronize requests for each iteration in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a thread group with 2 if controllers, which are responsible for uploading files and creating *2 types* of table. Condition for the first if ${__threadNum} % 2 ==0. Condition for the second if ${__threadNum} % 2 ==1. File 1 uploads for the first condition, file 2 for the second. See test tree in attach. I set 4 users and 10 loop count in thread group to **create 2 tables from the "file 1" and 2 tables from the "file 2"**. (The tables are different)

What i need is to measure the time of creation for each table from start ('run import" request) to end (when table is completely available in web). As you see in attach I created transaction controller and put required requests in it. I use While controller for get requests to catch the table update's finish. Everything works fine except one - **"run import" request must start simultaneously in each of the four threads for every iteration**.

I tried to use synchronization timer  for "run import" request in both If controllers, but test have paused infinitely.
Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

it's pausing infinitely because the sync timer waits to get enough Threads to sync. Your Problem sounds like that there are not enough Threads reaching this sync timer.

See [JMeter Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) for description

Try to set the User Count to 0 at the Sync Timer and he'll use all Threads who reach him. This might fix your problem?

Comment: I've tried to set the User Count to 0 at the Sync Timer, but the result is the same. The only point where I can synchronize the iterations is "Login" request, but I need another one.

Comment: See my post, i currently struggle with a simliar problem. May this will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784615/jmeter-synchronizing-requests-and-synchronizing-timer