# JMeter Synchronizing requests and Synchronizing Timer

Tags: transactions, request, synchronization, jmeter

I want to archive that various transaction controller(TA) with containing HTTP requests are always fired at the same time for each loop. Currently, he's just sending the first TA synchronized and the second one varies between 1-5 sec.

**JMeter Setup:**

[image]

- Thread Group: 5 Threads, 0 Ramp up, 5 Loops
- Synchronizing Timer: 0 and 30000 Timeout

**Result**

[image]

- View Results in Table(Filtered with Excel for Transaction Controller)

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing Synchronizing Timer. If you want to group samplers you need to put **5** into "Number of Simulated Users to Group By" input. If you keep **0** - there will be no effect.

[image: Synchronizing Timer Config]

Also it's better to remove top Synchronizing Timer (under the Thread Group).

[image: Synchronizing Timer Demo]

See [Using the JMeter Synchronizing Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) article for detailed information on how to use and where to put the timer.

Comment: Actually i want to sync my Transaction controller which contain a lot of requests. Each Transaction controller contains a lot of requests. I dont think (want) to put a Sync Timer to each request?

I read [JMeter Manual] [1] for explenation of this "group by" value and there is statet 0 means all Threads? I also tried 5 already.

Is there a way to start all Transaction controller one by one but with all Threads in sync? My target is to simulate 5 useres doing everything at the same time.

[1]: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer

Comment: @Sten Were you able to achieve what you are looking for? I have a similar question.

Comment: What number to put for Synchronizing Timer when I have 6 groups of samplers with 50 users and 10 loops? Should I add Synchronizing Timer for each group or create one global?